# Resave .MSG files when sending email

Tags: vb.net, email

I'm using vb.net to send email via .MSG file, I've tried with .OFT, both using createitemfromtemplate.

The emails will send, no problem. Works great. The only issue I have is anytime I restart, I have to resave the .msg or .oft files as the same file names in order for them to send again, otherwise it won't work anymore.

Any ideas as to why this is or how to fix this?

Example:

```
         Dim omsg As Object
                omsg = Outl.CreateItemfromtemplate("Custom Two.msg")
                omsg.To = (TextBox1.Text)
                omsg.Subject = (TextBox2.Text)

                omsg.Display(False) 'will display message to user
```

Someone suggested adding the files into memory before the application loads to correct this.. but I'm not 100% sure how to do this, other than it goes in the load events.. Any ideas?

Comment: Deleting this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found to be easiest for this is:

```
        Dim filelist() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath)
    For Each File In filelist
        If File.Contains(".oft") Or File.Contains(".msg") Then
            Dim temp1 As String = File.Replace(Application.StartupPath & "\", String.Empty)
            If File.Contains(".oft") Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(temp1)
            ElseIf File.Contains(".msg") Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(temp1)
            End If

        End If
```

Instead of trying to read them into a list one by one with names, linking them dynamically seems to fit better and execute without an issue.